# Unable to edit the user information in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here is my problem , So i wanted to only allowing the user to change/edit their password and username only.
My original model for customer is this

```
public string IC { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Username{ get; set; }
public string Password{ get; set; }
```

And this is my VM for the customer

```
public string Username{ get; set; }
public string Password{ get; set; }
```

And this is my controller for the edit function

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Username,Password")] CustomersVM customersVM )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(customersVM ).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(customersVM );
        }
```

view.cshtml

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IC)
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

So this VM is to let the ModelState goes valid, which is will going right into the database but it turn out to turn this type of error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type CustomerVM is not part of the model for the current context.'

Comment: This is an idea... are you sure that database has customersVM table?

Comment: What does the view look like?

Comment: @Dani No, i need to let the model state returning true right. So the VM is to let the returning true.But how do I let the newly edited value to pass into the database

Comment: @christiandev I have edited the question with the view added

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `CustomerVm`, I see a property for `CharityId`?

Comment: Oh i see forget to change that, so i now think that this might not working because of this line of code ```db.Entry(customersVM ).State = EntityState.Modified;``` am I right, @christiandev it is not suitable to use under this state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to edit/update a record, you need to identify that record first. I your case, your `ViewModel` is not what your database holds but the first model in your question. So you need to map that viewModel to the real model before saving or fetch the existing record then modify it then set it as modified before saving.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Username,Password")] CustomersVM customersVM )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var existing = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customersVM.Id);
                if (existing != null)
                {
                     existing.Username  = customersVM.Username;
                     existing.Password = customerVM.Password;
                     db.Entry(existing ).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(customersVM );
        }
```